# Möbius transform Tikz - special request

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I would need some picture in Tikz but I don't know how could I achieve them. ( I don't know if exsist some code of it).

There is a youtube video which shows the Möbius transforms in two dimension (these are the dilatation, translation, inversion, and rotation).
The link of the video is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JX3VmDgiFnY.

I would like get the picture of these transformation but in a special style. For example in the wikipedia there are some picture of them :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_conformal_transformation#/media/File:Conformal_grid_before_M%C3%B6bius_transformation.svg
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_conformal_transformation#/media/File:Conformal_grid_after_M%C3%B6bius_transformation.svg

In this style (with thin lines of the grid and with other color) the pictures of the transformation would be sufficient for me.

I would be thankful if someone could help me with it.

Comment: You can find the equation here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59271/mobius-transformations-revealed.

Comment: Can you tell us what have you tried so far?  And does it have to be done in TikZ?

Comment: Thank you Giacomo Alessandroni for your comment, it helps me so much.

Comment: This is the documentation that I found in SX, It seem me like a starting point.